# How to get td values and store in array using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can we read input value into an array for all td `array = [1,2,3]`.using pure javascript

I tried this but it creates an array of objects, but I  just want to store only values in an array. Can anyone tell how it can be accomplished?

```js
const array = [...document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr")].map((row) => {
  const [id] = [...row.querySelectorAll('td')].map(td => td.textContent.trim());
  return { id }
})
console.log(array);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="removeName(this);">Remove</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="id" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="removeName(this);">Remove</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="id" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="removeName(this);">Remove</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="3" name="id" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. It gives console errors until I change `Id` to `id`

Comment: Is your goal to get the `value` of each `input` inside of the `td`s? So `[1, 2, 3]`. Your title is confusing since you're asking to get `td` values, but `td`s don't have values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('td input');
values = [...inputs].map(input => input.value);
console.log(values);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="removeName(this);">Remove</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="id" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="removeName(this);">Remove</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="id" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="removeName(this);">Remove</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="3" name="id" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: This will fail as soon as another field is added or the button is changed to `input type="button"`

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap in {} you will get an object array

TO get the name=id value just do this - I added an ID to the tbody to narrow the selector

```
const ids = [...document.querySelectorAll("#tb [name=id]")]
 .map(fld => fld.value);
```

Here I get the values and the textContent

I also added an eventListener for the remove button

```js
// input value
const ids = [...document.querySelectorAll("#tb [name=id]")]
 .map(fld => fld.value);

console.log(ids);

// cell text content

const rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr");
const names = [...rows]
 .map(row => row.firstElementChild.textContent.trim())

console.log(names);

// not part of the question

document.getElementById("tb").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove")) {
    e.preventDefault(); // or have type="button"
    tgt.closest("tr").remove();
  }  
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>
        <button  class="remove">Remove</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="id" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>
        <button class="remove">Remove</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="id" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>
        <button class="remove">Remove</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="3" name="id" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @theWellHopeErr Please remove your comment - the error is not part of the question and has been solved

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this code is what you are looking for

```js
const array = [...document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr")].map((row) => {
  const tds = [...row.querySelectorAll('td')].map(td => td.textContent.trim());
  return tds
}).flat()
console.log(array);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="removeName(this);">Remove</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="id" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="removeName(this);">Remove</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="id" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="removeName(this);">Remove</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="3" name="id" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

if the td has input inside of it then the code will be

```
const array = [...document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr")].map((row) => {
      const tdInputs = [...row.querySelectorAll('td input')].map(ipnut => input.value.trim());
      return tdInputs
    }).flat()
    console.log(array);
```

Comment: I'm sure it isn't. I made you a snippet. See what it returns. Then read the question: `How can we read input value into an array for all td array = [1,2,3]`

Comment: if the td has input in it then we can change the code liek this
const tdInputss = [...row.querySelectorAll('td input')].map(input=> input.value.trim());